# ReferenceError: moment is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datatables, momentjs

I'm trying to use Ultimate date plugins for DataTables (http://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18). I have both file (moment.js 2.8.1 and datetime-moment.js plugin), they are load fine but when I use the syntax :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'DD/MM/YYYY' );

    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

I got an error : ReferenceError: moment is not defined

Don't know where is the problem...

Edit :

```
    <script src="/js/libs/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/libs/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/libs/validationEngine/js/languages/jquery.validationEngine-fr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/libs/validationEngine/js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/libs/underscore/underscore-1.7.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/libs/moment/moment-2.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/plugins/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/plugins/datatables/js/datetime-moment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/libs/highcharts/4.0.4/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/libs/highcharts/4.0.4/highcharts-more.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/libs/highcharts/4.0.4/modules/exporting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/libs/highcharts/4.0.4/modules/no-data-to-display.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: can u just show us the script tag of both moment.js 2.8.1 and datetime-moment.js?

Comment: I add them to the post ;)

Comment: IMHO it is because of some script tag if am not wrong u included jquery also right?

Comment: Yes, I add the complete scripts call of the application to the post..

Comment: Have u tried with CDN?

Comment: see this:http://datatables3.rssing.com/chan-5199417/all_p584.html

Comment: Same result with CDN

Comment: When I put the call to momentjs before or just after <body>, it work fine, but if I call it after, I got the error...